# recursive method for finding all decodings of a string of numbers

Tags: java, string, recursion, decoding, string-decoding

i am trying to find all possible decoding of a string of numbers, for example the following

```
Input: {1, 2, 1}
Output: ("aba", "au", "la") 
[3 interpretations: aba(1,2,1), au(1,21), la(12,1)]
```

My program pints "aba" then gives me the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at countDecoding.decodings(countDecoding.java:20)
at countDecoding.decodings(countDecoding.java:17)
at countDecoding.decodings(countDecoding.java:17)
at countDecoding.main(countDecoding.java:37)

line 20 is      if((str.charAt(n)<'2' && str.charAt(n+1)!='0')  || (str.charAt(n)=='2' && str.charAt(n+1)<'6')){

and line 17 is          decodings(str,n=n+1,temp,len);
```

below is my code

```
public class countDecoding {
static void decodings(String str, int n,String temp,int len){

    if(n == len ){
         System.out.println(temp);
        return;
    }

    if(str.charAt(n)>='0'){
        char[] c = Character.toChars(96 + str.charAt(n)-'0');
        temp = temp +c[0];
        decodings(str,n=n+1,temp,len);
    }

    if((str.charAt(n)<'2' && str.charAt(n+1)!='0')  || (str.charAt(n)=='2' && str.charAt(n+1)<'6')){

        String hold = "";
        hold+=str.charAt(n);
        hold+=str.charAt(n+1);
        char[] c = Character.toChars(96 + (Integer.parseInt(hold)));
        temp = temp +c[0];
        System.out.println("temp is "+temp);
        decodings(str,n=n+2,temp,len);
    }

}

public static void main(String[]args){

    String str="121";
    decodings(str, 0,"",3);

}

}
```

Please help me find what is wrong with my implementation. I suck at recursion, so i am trying to horn my skills. Thanks

Comment: Please tell us which line is line 20.

Comment: I suggest something like `System.out.println(n)` just before the `charAt` line that is causing the problem.  It will probably help you see what errors there may be in your logic.  Or use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the String goes from 0... n-1. Say length is 3 but the str.charAt(n) n should be from 0...2. You are calling it with 3 fix it.
The line if referring to is :

```
if(str.charAt(n)<'2' && str.charAt(n+1)!='0')  || (str.charAt(n)=='2' && str.charAt(n+1)<'6'))
```

Even after fix that you will get errors cause you are doing n+1 also in that same line.

---

EDIT: Check the code now:

```
private void decodings(String str, int n,String temp,int len){

    if(n == len ){
        System.out.println(temp);
        return;
    }

    if(str.charAt(n)>='0'){
        char[] c = Character.toChars(96 + str.charAt(n)-'0');
        temp = temp +c[0];
        decodings(str,n+1,temp,len);
    }
    System.out.println("temp is "+temp);
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    String str="121";
    new countDecoding().decodings(str, 0,"",3);
}
```

OUTPUT IS :

```
aba
temp is aba
temp is ab
temp is a
```

Comment: thanks, but i need those to check for (n) and (n+1). changing anything there will give me wring results, do you have any other ways i can implement this.

Comment: I could help you with he implementation if you give some sale input and sample output ! And explain what you want to do ! Also i don't understand what you mean by < in char comparison ?

Comment: Input: {1, 1}
Output: ("aa", 'k") 
[2 interpretations: aa(1, 1), k(11)]
   
Input: {1, 2, 1}
Output: ("aba", "au", "la") 
[3 interpretations: aba(1,2,1), au(1,21), la(12,1)]
    
Input: {9, 1, 8}
Output: {"iah", "ir"} 
  [2 interpretations: iah(9,1,8), ir(9,18)] ,  i basically want to have the output as intepretations, in form of a string

Comment: One of the problem is you are using static method for recursion. In that you were doing n=n+2 you should not do that ...

Comment: yh, but your output lacks "au" which is {1},{2,1}, and "la" which is {12},{1}

Comment: Yes now add that code the point was i removed static from your code and I changed n=n+2 in the parameter passing !

Comment: it gives  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
 at countDecoding.decodings(countDecoding.java:17)
 at countDecoding.decodings(countDecoding.java:13)
 at countDecoding.decodings(countDecoding.java:13)
 at countDecoding.main(countDecoding.java:32)